# How to prove this set equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I started as

$$\bar{X_1}\cup(\bar{X_2}\setminus(X_3\cap\bar{X_1})=\bar{X_1}\cup(\bar{X_2}\setminus X_3)\cup (\bar{X_2}\setminus \bar{X_1})=\bar{X_1}\cup(\bar{X_2}\setminus X_3)\cup \bar{X_2}=\bar{X_1}\cup \bar{X_2}$$

To simplify the left side, but I do not know how to proceed further with the proof itself :(

Comment: It seems that the simplification is correct.

Comment: If so, the problem amounts to showing that $\bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2} = \bar{X_1 }\cup \bar{X_2}\cup X_3$ iff...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, well, I am more confused about how to proof the whole equation, I tried "from the oposite" method, but it does not seem correct

Comment: You can proceed with $\to$ first and then $\leftarrow$. *Hint* for $\to$: assume the equality and assume for contradiction that $X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 \ne \emptyset$. Thus means that there is some $z : z \in X_1,X_2, X_3$. Thus $z \in X_3$ and $z \notin \bar{X_1} \cup \bar {X_2}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA guess something like: 

$$\bar{X_1} \cup\bar{X_2} \ne \bar{X_1}\cup\bar{X_2}\cup X_3$$

?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If you wrote up all these as a regular post, I would give you more karma for that as comments are not to increase the reputation :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can proceed with $\to$ first and then $←$.

For $→$ : assume that the equality holds and assume for contradiction that $X_1 ∩ X_2 ∩ X_3 \ne \emptyset$.

This means that, for some $z : z ∈ X_1,X_2,X_3$, and this in turn implies that:

> $z ∈ X_3$ and $z ∉ \bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2}$.

But thus : $z ∈ X_3 \cup \bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2}$.

In conclusion, we have that, for some $z : z ∉ \bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2}$ and $z ∈ X_3 \cup \bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2}$, contradicting the fact that the two are equals.

---

Similarly for $←$ : assume that $X_1 ∩ X_2 ∩ X_3 = \emptyset$ and assume for contradiction that $\bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2} \ne X_3 \cup \bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2}$.

This means that there is a $z$ such that $z ∈ X_3 \cup \bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2}$ and $z ∉ \bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2}$.

But $z ∉ \bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2}$ means that $z \in X_1$ and $z \in X_2$.

And $z ∉ \bar{X_1} ∪ \bar{X_2}$, with the fact that $z ∈ X_3 \cup \bar{X_1} \cup \bar{X_2}$, means that $z \in X_3$.

Thus :

> $z \in X_1,X_2,X_3$,

contradicting the fact that $X_1 ∩ X_2 ∩ X_3 = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from where you left off,
show the LHS is equivalent to both
 $X_3 \subseteq \bar{X_1}\cup\bar{X_2}$ 
and $X_1 \cap X_2 \subseteq \bar{X_3}.$
The rest is now apparent.